# Database not returning right values?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, prepared-statement

Alright so I currently have a database that has the following times:

> id 1 startTime 2013-09-09 15:05:10.0 endTime 2013-09-09 15:05:10.0
>
> id 2 startTime 2013-09-09 15:09:54.0 endTime 2013-09-09 15:09:54.0
>
> id 3 startTime 2013-09-09 15:20:46.0 endTime 2013-09-09 15:20:46.0
>
> id 4 startTime 2013-09-09 15:21:06.0 endTime 2013-09-09 15:21:06.0
>
> id 5 startTime 2013-09-09 15:21:34.0 endTime 2013-09-09 15:21:34.0
>
> id 6 startTime 2013-09-09 15:22:34.0 endTime 2013-09-09 15:22:34.0
>
> id 7 startTime 2013-09-09 15:23:06.0 endTime 2013-09-09 15:25:34.0

now when I run my search by time method located here:

```
@Override
public ArrayList<AppointmentAccess> searchByTime(Timestamp startTime,
        Timestamp endTime) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<AppointmentAccess> appointmentList = new ArrayList<AppointmentAccess>();

    String preparedQuery = "Select DISTINCT * From Appointments where startTime <= appointments.endTime AND endTime >= appointments.startTime";

    // Connect to database
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,
            password);

    // Run SQL
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(preparedQuery);

    // Get SQL results
    ResultSet query = ps.executeQuery();) {

        while (query.next()) {
            AppointmentAccess appointment = new AppointmentAccess();
            appointment.setStartTime(query.getTimestamp("starttime"));
            appointment.setEndTime(query.getTimestamp("endtime"));

                appointment.setAlarmReminder(query
                        .getBoolean("alarmreminder"));
                appointment.setAllDay(query.getBoolean("allday"));
                appointment.setDetails(query.getString("details"));
                appointment.setLocation(query.getString("location"));
                appointment.setTitle(query.getString("title"));
                appointmentList.add(appointment);
        }
    }
    // Returns a List of all the contacts
    return appointmentList;
}
```

my test methods "searchTooLate, searchTooEarly and searchTimeBetweenAppointments" keep failing.
The times i'm sending these methods are:

startTime: "2013-09-09 16:05:09"
endTime: "2013-09-09 16:22:35"

startTime: "2013-09-09 15:24:06.0"
endTime: "2013-09-09 15:25:30.0"

startTime:"2013-08-09 14:05:09"
endTime:"2013-08-09 16:22:35"

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: If you don't properly format the data people the less people will read your question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this part of your code: `String preparedQuery = "Select DISTINCT * From Appointments where startTime <= appointments.endTime AND endTime >= appointments.startTime";`

How do you propose that will change?   You're comparing startTime to "Appointments.editTime" every time (double quotes on purpose).  Which would cause the query to fail as Appointments.editTime is not a variable in the database.

Maybe you intended `..." + Appointments.startTime.ToString() + "...` Which is still the wrong way to do it, but this will make your code functional. Consider a PROC and parameters.